# more of something versus more something

Tags: prepositions

What guide lines are there in respect to the proper choice between "more of something" and "more something"? I can't see a logic behind it. Here are some examples which I think are correct, but I don't understand why they are the way they are.

I have **more free** time than she. (Why no OF?)

I have **more of a sense of humour** than she. (Why OF?)

It has even **more of a Disney vibe** to it. (Why OF?)

I need to eat more of Jack's pies. OR I need to eat more Jack's pies.

I need to read more God's words. OR I need to read more of God's words.

What guides the usage of OF?

Comment: There seems to be a different rule at work in each example sentence. There is quantity, quality, intensity, and more of individual vs more individuals.

Comment: It seems like if the word takes a determiner (a, Jack's, God's) then it needs *of*.  If there is no determiner, there is no *of*.  Consider: I have more toys than you, but some of my toys are broken.

Comment: Time is uncountable (doesn't need _of_). We can say _I have more sense of humour than she does_.

Comment: Kate, do you mean that "more of A sense of humour" and "more sense of humour" are correct?

Comment: stangdon, do you think that "I need to read more God's words." is wrong?

Comment: @user1425 Yes, "I need to read more God's words" sounds wrong.

Comment: @KateBunting To my ear, "more sense of humo(u)r" sounds wrong, but this may be a US/UK split.  Consider the [British Ngrams results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+sense+of%2Cmore+of+a+sense+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) vs [American Ngrams results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+sense+of%2Cmore+of+a+sense+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3).  (I had to leave out "humo(u)r" because of Ngrams search limitations.)

Comment: Why are both correct? I need to read more inspiring words. I need to read more of inspiring words.

Comment: @stangdon I did check Ngrams first to confirm my instinct that we (UK) can say _more sense of humour_.

Comment: @user1425 - With countable items, we don't use _of_ when the noun is preceded by an adjective or modifier (more pork pies), but we do when a particular group or category is identified (more of those pies, more of Jack's pies). It feels so natural to a native speaker, but is difficult to explain!

Comment: Kate, you think that this sentence is wrong "I need to read more of inspiring words."